# where is defined FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_SHARE_READ, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and

Tags: c#

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static IntPtr CreateFile(
            string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess,
            uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
            uint dwCreationDisposition,
            uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

 private IntPtr m_fileHandle;

m_fileHandle = CreateFile(m_logPath ,FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,                                OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL|FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN|FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH,NULL);
```

i have errors like this:

```
error CS0103: The name 'FILE_APPEND_DATA' does not exist in the current context
error CS0103: The name 'FILE_SHARE_READ' does not exist in the current context
```

how do i solve this errors? please help me.

Comment: pinvoke.net: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateFile.html

Comment: have i to define all (FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_SHARE_READ and ...) in my project?

Comment: @nabegheh95 yes, the C# compiler needs to know what FILE_APPEND_DATA is. Copy the whole definition for `enum EFileAccess` to your project.

Comment: They are defined in a Windows SDK header file.  Which does you little good, it can only be used by a C or C++ compiler.  The Pinvoke Interop Assistant is a handy tool to get them into your code.  Do note that there is no point at all in pinvoking CreateFile() like this, the .NET FileStream class already wraps it completely.  The only outlier is pinvoking it to open a device, not permitted by .NET since it cannot figure out if that is safe, that's not what you are doing when you open a log file.